# regexp for any character not containing a double-underscore

Tags: regex, python-2.7

How do you exclude matches based on strings containing a double-underscore?

e.g. I want to match `fiddle01`, `fi_ddle01`, but not `fi__ddle01`?

I know how to exclude at the start of a string but not in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*?__).*$
```